# perspective transform on uiview

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-animation

Here's the basic code to get started with:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                animations:^ {         

                    CALayer *layer1 = leftband.layer;
                    layer1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
                    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform1 = CATransform3DIdentity;
                    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform1.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
                    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform1 = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform1, DegreesToRadians(-180.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                    layer1.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform1;

                    CALayer *layer2 = rightband.layer;
                    layer2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
                    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2 = CATransform3DIdentity;
                    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
                    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2 = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2, DegreesToRadians(180.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                    layer2.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2;
                }
                completion:nil {

                }];
```

leftband and rightband are two UIImageViews. The effect I want is that the leftband animates with its transform along the Y-axis towards the left direction. And the rightband does the same along its Y-axis towards the right.

But the above code results in both left and right imageviews animating in the same direction (it happens only towards left). I guess my understanding of anchor points is wrong. Both -180° and +180° in the rotation transform result in a leftward animation.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First, your code doesn't even compile: `nil {}` is not a valid completion block. It should be:`^(BOOL finished) { ... }`. Second, we don't know the frames or anything about the leftband and rightband views. Third, "Here's the basic code to get started with:" sound a little bit like an assignment doesn't it? Some curtesy would probably make people want to help you a little bit more.

Comment: I'll be a little nice and tell you that you've seem to have gotten actor points wrong. If you want one side to animate to the left and the other to the right you shouldn't have the same anchor point for both. Go read the documentation again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically setting the anchor points before the animation block runs solves the issue. Anchor point for left -> (0.0f,0.5f) and for right -> (1.0f,0.5f).